# asp:UploadFile doesn't work in asp:updatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload a file with  that is in a updatepanel but doesn't work
this is error text : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
i use too ajaxtoolkitt but doesn't work.
Pleas help me
thank

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="S"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="U" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <div class="Div" style="box-shadow: 3px 2px 24px #000000">
            <div style="margin:0px auto;padding-top:10px">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Add_P">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>متن نمایشی</td>

                            <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Text_txt" CssClass="Txt-class"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>آدرس عکس</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="Address_FU"/>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Address_txt" Visible="false" CssClass="Txt-class"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="OK_btn" CommandName="Add" OnClick="On_click"  Text="ثبت" CssClass="btn-blue"/></td>
                            <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="Cancel_btn" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="btn-blue" Text="لغو" OnClick="On_click"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Address_FU.PostedFile.SaveAs("~/Image/a.jpg");
```

Comment: In `<table>`, the second `<tr>` block isn't closed

Comment: this is some code not all of them

Comment: are doing a post back to get the file? file upload is not working with ajax calls, you need a full post back.

Comment: sorry i use this code <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="Address_FU"/>

Comment: no body can help me!!!